# How to create text-to-speech with neural network

Tags: python, neural-network, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I am creating a Text to Speech system for a phonetic language called "Kannada" and I plan to train it with a Neural Network. The input is a word/phrase while the output is the corresponding audio.

While implementing the Network, I was thinking the input should be the segmented characters of the word/phrase as the output pronunciation only depends on the characters that make up the word, unlike English where we have slient words and Part of Speech to consider. However, I do not know how I should train the output.

Since my Dataset is a collection of words/phrases and the corrusponding MP3 files, I thought of converting these files to WAV using pydub for all audio files.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3("audio/file1.mp3")
sound.export("wav/file1.wav", format="wav")
```

Next, I open the wav file and convert it to a normalized byte array with values between 0 and 1.

```
import numpy as np
import wave

f = wave.open('wav/kn3.wav', 'rb')
frames = f.readframes(-1)

#Array of integers of range [0,255]
data = np.fromstring(frames, dtype='uint8')

#Normalized bytes of wav
arr  = np.array(data)/255
```

**How Should I train this?**

From here, I am not sure how to train this with the input text. From this, I would need a variable number of input and output neurons in the First and Last layers as the number of characters (1st layer) and the bytes of the corresponding wave (Last layer) change for every input.

Since RNNs deal with such variable data, I thought it would come in handy here.

Correct me if I am wrong, but the output of Neural Networks are actually probability values between 0 and 1. However, we are not dealing with a classification problem. The audio can be anything, right? In my case, the "output" should be a vector of bytes corrusponding to the WAV file. So there will be around 40,000 of these with values between 0 and 255 (without the normalization step) for every word. How do I train this speech data? Any suggestions are appreciated.

**EDIT 1** : In response to **Aaron's** comment

From what I understand, Phonemes are the basic sounds of the language. So, why do I need a neural network to map phoneme labels with speech? Can't I just say, "whenever you see this alphabet, pronounce it like *this*". After all, this language, Kannada, is phonetic: There are no silent words. All words are pronounced the same way they are spelled. How would a Neural Network help here then?

On input of a new text, I just need to break it down to the corresponding alphabets (which are also the phonemes) and retrieve it's file (converted from WAV to raw byte data). Now, merge the bytes together and convert it to a wav file.

Is this this too simplistic? Am I missing something here? What would be the point of a Neural Network for this particular language (Kannada) ?

Comment: In brief, you have to come up with a feature list. What goes into the list and how it is measured and represented, depends on the problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: I already know the features of the input text. I'm not concerned about the input format. It's the output layer that I'm stumped on. How do I train the speech OUTPUT on the text input with the neural network?

Comment: You need to first find a way to translate the text into phonemes. This is more typically done with curated databases than learning algorithms, but in your case is what you're really doing with the neural net. audio files of recorded phonemes are more or less appended together to form words.

Comment: I edited my answer in response to @Aaron 's comment. Please check EDIT 1 of my answer.

Comment: @AjayH I just did some preliminary (Wikipedia) research on Kannada, and while in general it was stated that it is purely phonetic, it did also mention at least one instance where that rule is broken. Also mentioned was that there were as many as 20 dialects. While the trivial approach may be sufficient for many instances, you should still definitely include a framework to add overrides for larger (than single letter) patterns where exceptions need to be made.

Comment: @Aaron This brings me back to the original question. How should I train the speech data? NNs are Probabilistic. How do I convert WAV files to give probabilities? (Sorry for all these questions, I am just stumped on this)

Comment: @AjayH that goes to what Nikolay posted about. It's an area of active research, but modern text to speech does not use NNs for this purpose. They use pre-recorded audio files of phonemes. I believe even the most modern (commertial) text to speech programs do not really use NNs at all yet. They use well curated dictionaries and hand written rules to handle cases outside the dictionary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139268/discussion-between-aaron-and-ajay-h).

Answer (score 1):

It is not trivial and requires special architecture. You can read the description of it in a publications of [DeepMind](https://deepmind.com/blog/wavenet-generative-model-raw-audio/) and [Baidu](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.07825).

You might also want to study [existing implementation of wavenet training](https://github.com/ibab/tensorflow-wavenet).

Overall, pure end-to-end speech synthesis is still not working. If you are serious about text-to-speech it is better to study conventional systems like [merlin](https://github.com/CSTR-Edinburgh/merlin).

Comment: I edited my answer under EDIT 1 (in response to another comment) . Can you let me know your thoughts on that.