# Building speech to text neural network on RaspberryPi

Tags: neural-network

I want to build a neural network, or generally to code a system capable on fitting on embedded devices (like RaspberryPi) that can transform anything I say to text. Is it something that can be done? I searched on the internet and I found some programs that either work online or that are ready applications. I don't want that, I want to build an **open source code** for doing this translation from speech to text. I also searched on stackoverflow, and I have found this link: [How to create text-to-speech with neural network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43053969/how-to-create-text-to-speech-with-neural-network) but I want the opposite (speech to text). I am not looking for ready patterned words that could identify. I am thinking of raw speech, that can identify it and transform it to text. Any ideas where should start from?

Comment: Why downvoted?? I have searched on the internet I have posted links, I specifally explain what I am trying to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you are looking for is a neural network that takes a stream of data as input (an audio file) and produces a stream of data as output (for example ascii text).

In order to do so, I'd suggest you to acquire a good insight and intuition on a few topics:

- **Logistic Regression**
- **Deep Neural Networks**
- **Convolutional Neural Networks**
- **Recurrent Neural Networks**
- **Reinforcement Learning** - I don't think this one is necessary, but it will probably help you train your model much faster

Of course acquiring a sufficient knowledge in these topics involves several hours of studying and practicing, but the internet is full of great courses about all of them.

Good luck!